# Laravel scheduling container

Tags: laravel

I've implemented scheduled tasks following Laravel's doc:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling

Its working fine, but I was wondering what would be the best way to contain the tasks so if one fails the others are still good to go.

I'm using this function to handle the scheduling and to call for specific tasks in the Console's Kernel:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
        $schedule->call(function () {
            echo 'imagine this one will fail';
        })->daily();

        $schedule->call(function () {
            echo 'this one always succeed';
        })->daily();
}
```

I've failsafe at the function's level but I was wondering if there was another level of containment I could use at the Console's Kernel level?

Thank you!

Adrien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not concerned about exceptions and just want to continue processing the scheduled tasks, then wrap the contents of each `$schedule->call` in the [rescue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-rescue) helper method. It will still report exceptions but allow processing to continue:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        rescue(function () {
            echo 'imagine this one will fail';
        });
    })->daily();

    $schedule->call(function () {
        rescue(function () {
            echo 'this one always succeed';
        });
    })->daily();
}
```

Rescue also takes a second parameter to take an action if the first does cause an exception:

```
$schedule->call(function () {
    rescue(function () {
        echo 'imagine this one will fail';
    }, function () {
        event(new ScheduledTaskFailed('some task blah blah...'));
    });
})->daily();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that was the idea!